# WordPress sets the homepage to index.php instead of default.php

Tags: web-development, wordpress, homepage

I'm using free hosting with `000webhost.com`, for that the default page it loads is `default.php`. But I've installed WordPress and now WordPress generated `index.php` as its homepage file.

As an easy solution, I just redirected from `default.php` to `index.php` when the page loads using the code:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://thigale.com/" />
```

But can anyone suggest me any other way? Instead of this stupid process?

Comment: Please explain what you don't like about the current setup.  Would you rather do a real redirect rather than an meta refresh?  Do you want index.php to become the homepage?

Comment: Yes. I want index.php to become my homepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For servers using **Apache** as a server you can create a file named *.htaccess* in the root of the domain with the content:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

The Apache server must also have *.htaccess* enabled. If the *.htaccess* file already exists you should add the line above to the existing file.

Comment: It should work for subdomains too?

Comment: Yes, that will work for subdomains too if you put the setting in the .htaccess file for each subdomain.